# unable to handle error while using defer in react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm learning react-router. I made a simple app in which I'm using data loaders for fetching data before rendering my component. I'm deferring the data fetch and then using `Suspense` and `Await`.

I have an error element defined in the `Route path="/" element={<Layout/>} errorElement={<Error/>}`. Whenever there is an error while fetching the data, it does not render this error component. It shows this error
[image]

I see that this error is from my component where the fetch function is being called `export function loader() { return defer({ bookmarks: getBookmarks() }); }`

please help.

Here is my Home.js which is being rendered.

```
import React, { Suspense } from "react";
import { getBookmarks } from "./api";
import { useLoaderData, defer, Await } from "react-router-dom";
export function loader() {
  return defer({ bookmarks: getBookmarks() });
}
export default function Home() {
  const dataPromise = useLoaderData();
  function renderBookMarks(bookmarks) {
    console.log(bookmarks);
    const bookmarksArr = bookmarks.data;
    const bookmarksElements = bookmarksArr.map(bookmark =>{
      return(
        <div key={bookmark.id} className="bookmark">
            <a target="#" href={bookmark.url} className="bookmark-element">{bookmark.title}</a>
        </div>
      )
    })

    return(
      <div className="bookmark-container">
        <h1>Search bookmarks</h1>
        {bookmarksElements}
      </div>
    )
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <Suspense fallback={<h2>Loading...</h2>}>
        <Await resolve={dataPromise.bookmarks}>
          {renderBookMarks}
        </Await>
      </Suspense>
    </div>)
}
```

here is my api.js:

```
import config from "./config";

const apiUrl = config.apiUrl;
const apiPort = config.apiPort;
const joinUrl = (baseUrl, url) => {
  return `${baseUrl}/${url}`;
};
const domain = `${apiUrl}:${apiPort}/api/bookmarks`;

export async function getBookmarks(url = "") {
  url = joinUrl(domain, URL);

    const res = await fetch(URL);
    if (!res.ok) {
      throw Object.assign(new Error("Failed to fetch data"), {
        message: "Failed to fetch data",
        statusText: res.statusText,
        status: res.status,
      });
    }
    const data = await res.json();
    return data;

}
```

here is my Error.js:

```
import React from "react";
import { useRouteError } from "react-router-dom";
export default function Error() {
  const error = useRouteError();
  console.log({error})
  return (<div>
    <h1>Oops! Something Went Wrong</h1>
    <h1>{error.message}</h1>
  </div>)
}
```

here is my Index.jsx where the route is defined:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import Layout from './components/Layout';
import Error from './components/Error';
import './index.css';
import {
  RouterProvider,
  createHashRouter,
  createRoutesFromElements,
  Route,
} from "react-router-dom";
import Home,{loader as bookmarksLoader} from './Home';
import AddBookMark from './AddBookMark';

const hashRouter = createHashRouter(createRoutesFromElements(
  <Route path="/" element={<Layout/>} errorElement={<Error/>}>
    <Route index element={<Home/>} loader={bookmarksLoader} />
    <Route path='addBookMarks' element={<AddBookMark/>}/>
  </Route>
)
)
function App() {
  return (
    <RouterProvider router={hashRouter} />
  )
}
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(<App />
);
```

sandbox image :
[image]

Comment: I've copy/pasted your code into a running [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/unable-to-handle-error-while-using-defer-in-react-router-dom-t844rh) (*I had to use a different API endpoint and adjust*) and the code appears to work as expected. When the fetch is successful, the UI updates, when the fetch fails the `Error` component is rendered. Think you could create a ***running*** [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io) demo of your own that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live?

Comment: in my case, when I'm trying to fetch the URL, the URL is unreachable. Will that change anything?

Comment: I don't believe it should. If the URL is unreachable then there's nothing to fetch and an error is returned. That's how I tested failure, by blocking the API in the browser devtools.

Comment: I changed the URL to "http://localhost:8080" in your sandbox project, and I see it is not rendering the error page. I have attached the screenshot in the question.

Comment: That's the same thing I see when inducing an error. I believe this is expected behavior when using error boundaries in non-production builds, so as you can see your `Error` component correctly rendered there under the React error overlay. If you look closely enough in your original image, it also is correctly rendering the `Error` component.

Comment: it leads to a bad user experience, right? If I try to achieve the same using react state hooks it would work just fine. Wonder why it does not work using loaders.

Comment: Rendering the `Error` component? No, that seems like a good thing to do, rendering fallback/error UI when an exception happens. What isn't working? From what I can tell it's all working as expected. https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html

Comment: The `Error` component is being rendered in rendered in the background. That's a good thing. But I don't understand why the Brown screen with the exception is shown.

Comment: It's shown in development builds, typically to indicate to developers an error hit a boundary and you should maybe take a look at it. In this case though, you're sort of expecting the error to hit there and display the fallback UI.